# Swift Read values in a plist in sandbox, not in app bundle

Tags: ios, swift, plist, sandbox

I want to read values from a plist file which located in sandbox path, because it is downloaded from the internet. I tried the following ways to load the plist file, but it always returns `nil`.

```
  NSArray(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fullpath))
  NSArray(contentsOfFile: fullpath)
```

The plist contents look like this:

```
<plist>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>DetailedTitle</key>
        <string>this is title</string>
        <key>Thumbnail</key>
        <string>https://www.google.com/w.jpg</string>
        <key>VideoURL</key>
        <string>http://www.google.com</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `fullPath`?

Comment: `fullpath` just like this `NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/data/12345data.plist"`

Comment: That won't work on iOS.  You need to access the sandbox documents directory `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]`